# Producer Consumer model using TPL, Tasks in .net 4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a fairly large XML file(around 1-2GB).

The requirement is to persist the xml data in to database.
Currently this is achieved in 3 steps.

1. Read the large file with less memory foot print as much as possible
2. Create entities from the xml-data
3. Store the data from the created entities in to the database using SqlBulkCopy.

To achieve better performance I want to create a Producer-consumer model where the producer creates a set of entities say a batch of 10K and adds it to a Queue. And the consumer should take the batch of entities from the queue and persist to the database using sqlbulkcopy.

Thanks,
Gokul

```
void Main()
{
    int iCount = 0;
    string fileName = @"C:\Data\CatalogIndex.xml";

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("Start Time: {0}", startTime);
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
    Console.WriteLine("File Size:{0} MB", fi.Length / 1048576.0);

/* I want to change this loop to create a producer consumer pattern here to process the data parallel-ly
*/
     foreach (var element in StreamElements(fileName,"title"))
            {
                iCount++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", iCount);
            Console.WriteLine("End Time: {0}, Time Taken:{1}", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now - startTime);
        }

    private static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamElements(string fileName, string elementName)
    { 
        using (var rdr = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
        {
            rdr.MoveToContent();
            while (!rdr.EOF)
            {
                if ((rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (rdr.Name == elementName))
                {
                    var e = XElement.ReadFrom(rdr) as XElement;
                    yield return e;
                }
                else
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                }
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried using Thread local storage, but as of now I am using only a single threaded approach of just calling a method to create the entities and then to persist them synchronously.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
    void Main()
    {
        const int inputCollectionBufferSize = 1024;
        const int bulkInsertBufferCapacity = 100;
        const int bulkInsertConcurrency = 4;

        BlockingCollection<object> inputCollection = new BlockingCollection<object>(inputCollectionBufferSize);

        Task loadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (object nextItem in ReadAllElements(...))
            {
                // this will potentially block if there are already enough items
                inputCollection.Add(nextItem);
            }

            // mark this collection as done
            inputCollection.CompleteAdding();
        });

        Action parseAction = () =>
        {
            List<object> bulkInsertBuffer = new List<object>(bulkInsertBufferCapacity);

            foreach (object nextItem in inputCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                if (bulkInsertBuffer.Length == bulkInsertBufferCapacity)
                {
                    CommitBuffer(bulkInsertBuffer);
                    bulkInsertBuffer.Clear();
                }

                bulkInsertBuffer.Add(nextItem);
            }
        };

        List<Task> parseTasks = new List<Task>(bulkInsertConcurrency);

        for (int i = 0; i < bulkInsertConcurrency; i++)
        {
            parseTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(parseAction));
        }

        // wait before exiting
        loadTask.Wait();
        Task.WaitAll(parseTasks.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for the psuedo-code. This is a good start. How do we make the CommitBuffer method to execute in parallel in X number of threads. Since persisting the data to the database in a time-consuming operation I would like to perform it as a multi-threaded operation with configurable number of threads. I will try implementing this code and update here.

Comment: @user943141 - That wont make much difference. If you really want to, you can start the parseTasks multiple times. However, a database operation is a heavy IO reliable operation. You will probably only slow things down using multiple threads since the IO is the bottleneck and synchronization is heavy

Comment: Please refer this article http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2009/11/30/sqlbulkcopy-performance-analysis.aspx where Alberto has created a PC model to perform the bulk insert of data. In this case the consumers are multi-threaded and perform sqlbulkcopy.

Comment: I havent red the post since i'm in china without my VPN right now, yet i've edited my code to support multiple parsing tasks. Still i dont think it will do any good but i will leave that decision up you